# Access input ID of reactive radioButtons in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, reactive

I am trying to create a shiny app which includes radioButtons which are reactive to some user input.

I was successful to implement the code from this related question:
[Add n reactive radioButtons to shiny app depending on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337549/add-n-reactive-radiobuttons-to-shiny-app-depending-on-user-input)

However, in this question it is not described how to access this values.

Here is the example:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

  output$variables <- renderUI({
    numVar <- length(as.integer(input$in0))

    lapply(input$in0, function(x) {
    list(radioButtons(paste0("dynamic",x), x, 
                     choices = c("Choice one" = "one", 
                                 "Choice two" = "two"), selected = "one"))
    })
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar (

  headerPanel("mtcars subset"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'in0', label = 'Choose variables', 
                choices = colnames(mtcars), 
                multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE),
    uiOutput("variables")
  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

What I have tried so far:

```
 numVar <- length(as.integer(input$in0))

for(i in 1:numVar){

in <- noquote(paste0("dynamic",input$in0[i])) 
input$in

}
```

However, this does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You were almost there. However, you'll have to make sure, that you are accessing the inputs in a reactive context.

Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pageWithSidebar (
    headerPanel("mtcars subset"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = 'in0', label = 'Choose variables', 
                  choices = colnames(mtcars), 
                  multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE),
      uiOutput("variables")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("myChoicesDisplay")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$variables <- renderUI({
    lapply(input$in0, function(x) {
      list(radioButtons(paste0("dynamic", x), x, 
                        choices = c("Choice one" = "one", 
                                    "Choice two" = "two"), selected = "one"))
    })

  })

  myChoices <- reactive({
    dynInputList <- list()
    for(dynInputs in paste0("dynamic", input$in0)){
      dynInputList[[dynInputs]] <- input[[dynInputs]]
    }
    return(dynInputList)
  })

  output$myChoicesDisplay <- renderText({
    paste(input$in0, myChoices(), sep = ": ", collapse = ", ")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly of your use case but to access the values you could edit your code as below:

```
numVar <- length(as.integer(input$in0))

for(i in 1:numVar){

value <- paste0("dynamic",input$in0[i])
input[[value]]

}
```

Basically you need to use `input[[value]]` as opposed to `input$value` in this case. It doesn't seem that R allows you to use `in` as a variable (probably because it's already used in other contexts). You don't need `noquote()` anymore.